# Echo JSON in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm currently learning about RESTful API's. I can currently print JSON to the console but how would I achieve echoing it out to an actual web page... Any advice would be much appreciated.. Please see my code below.

```js
$(document).on("ready", function(){
  loadData();
}); 
   
var loadData = function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"api.php"
  }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var post = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i in post){
      $("#content").append(post[ i ].usuario + " " + post[ i ].nombres + "<br>");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` return ?

Comment: @Aurel Returns table contents from a DB in JSON.

Comment: Why are you saying you "cant currently print JSON" then ?

Comment: Echo it out to a webpage... only to console?  @Aurel

Comment: Apologies...  I can print to console but NOT echo out the JSON to a web page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use jquery .each() loop, it should be useful in your case (iterating on JSON object)

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Remember the difference between Array type and Object type; you cant iterate with simple 'FOR' loop on object - object has no iterate value - objects have keys that you must call to get the data. For example:

```
var object = { name: 'Foo' }
```

To get the "Foo" value you have to call: `object.name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forEach](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) to iterate through an array in Javascript.

```js
$(document).on("ready", function(){
  loadData();
}); 
       
var loadData = function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"api.php"
  }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var post = JSON.parse(data);
        
    // Foreach item in post
    post.forEach(item, index) {
      $("#content").append(item.usuario + " " + item.nombres + "<br>");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```